# "Error creating variant or safe array" in TClientDataSet.LoadFromStream() in Delphi

Tags: c++, database, delphi, tcp, c++builder

I have a client-server application.
The client (TCP Client) is a Delphi application that sends commands to the server (TCP Server, C++ Builder application).
Both of them were written in **Rad Studio XE2**.
The server, in response to commands, fetches data from SQL Server and sends it to the client.
The server uses **TClientDataSet** and saves it to **TMemoryStream** that is sent to the client.
The client also uses **TClientDataSet** and calls **TClientDataSet.LoadFromStream()** on the stream received from the server.
This is working well.
But there is a case where size of data is larger (~160 MB) in which sometimes **"Error creating variant or safe array"** is being thrown upon calling **TClientDataSet.LoadFromStream()** in the client.

The server sends the stream to the client in this way:

```
//...
FContext->Connection->IOHandler->LargeStream = true;
FContext->Connection->IOHandler->Write(Stream, 0, true);
```

The client receives it in this way:

```
AClient.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
AClient.IOHandler.ReadStream(Stream, -1, False);
```

After the client receives, it changes the stream's position to 18.
Because actual data starts after 18 bytes. And then it calls **TClientDataSet.LoadFromStream()**.

```
//...
MemTable.LoadFromStream(Stream);
```

And **LoadFromStream()** is throwing **"Error creating variant or safe array"**.
But there were cases in which it worked without errors.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried creating a test stream of the exact same size, without involving your server, and checking whether the client CDS can do a LoadFromStream from that?

Comment: @MartynA I tested this in the server itself. That is, I called **LoadFromStream()** on another CDS for the same stream. It didn't throw the error. But it threw in the client.

Comment: Well, I guess that difference between server and client might help you rule out/in the cause that @KenBourassa has suggested - at the moment it sounds the most plausible explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Delphi 10's source code, the problem comes from `SafeArrayCreate` failing, most likely because of an EOutOfMemory exception.

`SafeArrayCreate` tries to allocate 160MB of memory, which needs to be contiguous. It's possible there is not a big enough "hole" in the virtual memory of your process to fit that much memory. In a 32 bits process, that wouldn't be that unlikely I guess.

One way to mitigate the problem a little would probably be to activate the /LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag. But that would only slightly reduce the likelyhood of the error happening, and could reappear soon in the future.

Other options would include :

- Compiling to a 64 bits application.
- Use a proper database instead of an in-memory dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. I will try with /LARGEADDRESSAWARE.

Comment: Enabling `/LARGEADDRESSAAWARE` without actually writing LAA-aware code and using a LAA-aware memory manager can cause other problems that are not easy to debug.  Use with caution!

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you.